# Pixel transparency in Leaflet ImageOverlay?

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to filter out the extraneous (low-Dbz) colors from this radar image.

```
 L.imageOverlay("http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Conus/RadarImg/latest_radaronly.gif?t" + Date.now(), [
                [50.406626367301044, -127.620375523875420], [21.65253806280344, -66.517937876818]
            ]).addTo(map);
```

Is it possible to set one or a range of colors as transparent in raster imageOverlays in Leaflet?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is really:

> My web browser is loading an image and displaying it "as is". How can I load the image, apply a filter function to all its pixels, and then display the result?

Please note that Leaflet does not include any such functionality.

In the JS world, there are two ways to achieve this:

- [Pixel manipulation with 2D `<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)
- Using more complex but insanely faster [WebGL shaders for image manipulation](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html)

It is possible to wrap these techniques in Leaflet plugins. See, for example, [`L.TileLayer.GL`](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL), which allows to conditionally manipulate pixel colours in a `TileLayer`, or the simpler [`L.TileLayer.PixelFilter`](https://github.com/GreenInfo-Network/L.TileLayer.PixelFilter/) and [`L.TileLayer.Grayscale`](https://github.com/Zverik/leaflet-grayscale/blob/master/TileLayer.Grayscale.js) which both use the slower 2D `<canvas>` API.

It should be possible to create a [Leaflet plugin](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) to achieve similar effects on `L.ImageOverlay`s instead of `L.TileLayer`s, but as far as I'm aware, nobody has done that yet. I suggest you consider doing so, reading the plugin tutorials and Leaflet's source code for `L.ImageOverlay` first.